# C++ Exercise Pancakes

Tags: c++

i am a begginer in c++
Now i am stuck on a exercise and i dont know how to solve it

The goal of the exercise is: Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people and make a list from the highest to the smallest like:
Person 6 ate: 10 pancakes
Person 1 ate: 6 pancakes
etc ...

i have this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int person_num = 0;
    int pancakes;
    vector<int> pancake_list;


    while (true) {

        person_num = person_num + 1;
        cout << "Please enter the number of pancakes eaten by Person #" << person_num << " ";
        cin >> pancakes;
        pancake_list.push_back(pancakes);

        sort(begin(pancake_list), end(pancake_list));
        reverse(begin(pancake_list), end(pancake_list));

        if (person_num == 10) {
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < pancake_list.size(); i++) {
                cout << pancake_list[i] << endl;
            }
            system("pause");
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that i dont know how to assign the sorted and reversed pancakes to the right person
Help please and explain

Sorry for my english

Comment: Have you asked your instructor for help?

Comment: You could use a map to store a value (number of pancakes) against a key (person number). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: This is not from school, i am learning c++ because i really love programming and this exercise is from a website

Comment: Typical software flow: input, process, output.  Ask all input, then process it, then print the result.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something with [c++ map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/). If you know you want things sorted, you can make use of the map key sorting to make life a bit easier for you. In this case, use the number of pancakes eaten as the key in the map, and the person number as the value - that way the list is already sorted, and you can just iterate backwards to print it in reverse sorted order. Something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int person_num = 0;
int pancakes;
multimap<int, int> pancake_map;// Use multimap incase two people ate the same number of pancakes. Note: there are no guarantees about the relative order of elements with the same key.


while (true) {

        person_num = person_num + 1;
        cout << "Please enter the number of pancakes eaten by Person #" << person_num << " ";
        cin >> pancakes;
        pancake_map.insert(make_pair(pancakes,person_num));// c++ multimap stores things sorted by key value, so we don't have to do any sorting

        if (person_num == 10) 
        {
            system("cls");
            // to print the ascending sorted list, iterate through the container forwards
            for (multimap<int,int>::iterator it=pancake_map.begin(); it != pancake_map.end(); ++it) 
            {
                cout << "Person number " << it->second << " ate " << it->first << " pancakes." << endl;
            }

            cout << endl;// little bit of formatting...
            // to print the reverse sorted list, iterate backwards
            for (multimap<int,int>::reverse_iterator it=pancake_map.rbegin(); it != pancake_map.rend(); ++it) 
            {
                cout << "Person number " << it->second << " ate " << it->first << " pancakes." << endl;
            }


            system("pause");
            break; // I added this to escape the loop after entering 10 people, remove it if you want.
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using number of pancakes as the key only works if every person eats a different number of pancakes.

Comment: Depends what you mean by works. The code compiles and does something sensible, because multimap can handle equal keys, but the ordering you will get is essentially undefined because no guarantees are made about the ordering of equal keys. If you don't care too much about the order the people are reported in at the end, it is okay.

Comment: @Theolodus: The word you're looking for is "unspecified ordering". In C++, "unspecified" is used for "any result from a countable set of possible results, all of which are reasonable outcomes". Here, there are N! orderings possible, which is clearly a finite set. "Undefined" OTOH typically is used as "Undefined Behavior" which may include formatting your harddisk and who knows what else. So don't use "undefined" unless you really mean UB.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of the vector there could be used an array because the number of elements is small and fixed.

One of solutions can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> pancake_list[N];

    std::cout << "Please enter the number of pancakes eaten by "
              << N << " persons: ";

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; n < N && std::cin >> pancake_list[n].second; n++ )
    {
        pancake_list[n].first = n + 1;
    }

    std::sort( pancake_list, pancake_list + n,
               []( auto &a, auto &b ) { return b.second < a.second; } );


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Person #" << pancake_list[i].first 
                  << " ate " << pancake_list[i].second
                  << " pancakes." << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

For example if to enter the following sequence of pancakes

6 2 8 7 1 4 6 3 5 0

then the output will look like

```
Person #4 ate 7 pancakes.
Person #1 ate 6 pancakes.
Person #7 ate 6 pancakes.
Person #9 ate 5 pancakes.
Person #6 ate 4 pancakes.
Person #8 ate 3 pancakes.
Person #2 ate 2 pancakes.
Person #5 ate 1 pancakes.
Person #10 ate 0 pancakes.
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you used some c++11 in there (auto keyword and a lambda function?). This is fine (and c++11 is probably what the questioner should be learning tbh), but the he didn't state wether he was using c++11.

Comment: @Theolodus I think that if he will have some troubles with the code he always can write a comment to the post himself, can't he?

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions so far are using a pair of (person#,pancakes) integers. That's one solution. Another is to realize that your problem is caused by the fact that you've not kept the original order. When you sorted the result, you replaced the original order with a new order. But if you sort a copy, you still have the original order and you can just match the two.

Using your code as a basis:

```
// Ask the use how many pancakes
vector<int> pancake_copy = pancake_list;

sort(begin(pancake_copy), end(pancake_copy));
reverse(begin(pancake_copy), end(pancake_copy));

// You know have the sorted and the unsorted lists. 
for (int numPancakes : pancake_copy)
{
   std::cout << numPancakes " pancakes were eaten by: ";
   for (int person = 0; person != pancake_list.size(); ++person)
   {
      if (pancakes_list[person] == numPancakes)
      {
         // This person ate numPancakes
         std::cout << i << " ";
      }
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Bonus exercise: What goes wrong now when two people eat the same number of pancakes? Which C++ function can you use to fix this?